# Recursive loop is not working with BackgroundWorker to get information from Outlook PST file

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I'm trying to loop through an Outlook PST file to collect some property information from each email within each folder & sub-folder using a recursive loop. And I'm trying to achieve this through a BackgroundWorker so that my Form UI don't freeze. But the problem is it's not working as expected, It's not looping recursively and gets exited after couple hundred iteration in Inbox where as I have more then 20 folder and sub-folder and 40,000+ emails.

```
Dim IndexDict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Const PropName As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102"
Dim skey As String
Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

Sub PrepareIndexing
    Dim dFolderR As Outlook.Folder
    dFolderR = oNspace.Folders.Item(dName)
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(dFolderR)
End Sub

Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim f As Outlook.Folder = CType(e.Argument, Outlook.Folder)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    InitIndexing(f, worker, e)
End Sub

Sub InitIndexing(f As Outlook.Folder, ByVal worker As BackgroundWorker, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    If f.Folders.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    For c = 1 To f.Folders.Count
        Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder = f.Folders.Item(c)
        For Each ml In Folder.Items
            oPA = ml.PropertyAccessor
            skey = oPA.BinaryToString(oPA.GetProperty(PropName))
            If Not DestinationIndexDict.ContainsKey(skey) Then
                IndexDict.Add(skey, Folder.FolderPath)
            End If
        Next
        InitIndexing(Folder, worker, e)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `For c = 0 to f.Folders.Count - 1`

Comment: When you first enter your InitIndexing sub, you never look through f.items...you just jump straight to iterating its sub-folders. If you only look at f's sub-folders and those sub-folders' items, you end up skipping a lot of items that are in f itself. The sub should be structured to iterate the items of the folder it was initially passed as an argument, and only re-call itself when it encounters a sub-folder during iteration

Comment: Does it raise an error? Or just exit the "for" loop?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, it doesn't generate any error , just exited the `For` loop randomly after couple hundred email loops in `Inbox`

Comment: You are probably getting an error, but since it's on a separate thread, you aren't seeing it.  Debug - Exceptions - check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and run your program again.

Comment: Loops don't just exit. How did you declare the ml variable? Keep in mind that you can have objects other than MailItem.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I'm searching all `Folder.Items` for a common property existed in all `Folder.Items`

Comment: I understand that, bit was ml variable declared?

Comment: No, I mean it just used here directly `For Each ml In Folder.Items`

Answer (score 0):

Any OOM calls should be done on the main thread.

Outlook Object Model is run in a STA COM server. This means that all OOM calls are executed on the main thread. If you are building an add-in that is making OOM calls from another thread (other than the main thread), then your calls need to be properly marshaled back to thread 0. For unmanaged code, you should use CoMarshalInterface or CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream to marshal your object pointer across threads. This will ensure your OOM calls are properly executed on thread 0. If you are writing managed code, using the OOM through COM interop by means of the PIA will actually handle this marshalling for you. Read more about that in the [Outlook Crashes When Using Outlook Object Model in Multiple Threads](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pcreehan/2008/03/13/outlook-crashes-when-using-outlook-object-model-in-multiple-threads/) article.